# URL errónea en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7

Estoy empezando con laravel y estoy teniendo un problema con la ruta en el browser. Cuando edito un producto en la base de datos, quiero me devuelva a la página principal.

El caso es que vuelvo a la página principal (todo funciona correctamente) pero se queda con la URL `homestead.test/update/1` cuando debería ser `homestead.test`.

Esto es lo que he intentado. La función `update` que redirige a la página principal que es `welcome`:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //Se edita el producto en la DB...

        $productos = App\Producto::all();
        return View('welcome', compact('productos'));
    }
```

Las rutas que tengo en `web.php`:

```php
Route::get('/', 'ProductoController@index')->name('inicio');
Route::post('/add', 'ProductoController@store')->name('add');
Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'ProductoController@edit')->name('edit');
Route::get('/destroy/{id}', 'ProductoController@destroy')->name('destroy');
Route::put('/update/{id}', 'ProductoController@update')->name('update');
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: No debes de retonar una vista, lo que debes de hacer es una redireccion de url mas o menos asi: `return redirect('/')->with(compact('productos'))`;

Comment: Funcionó perfecto. Esto corrigió el error. Añádela como respuesta si quieres. Un saludo y gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando retornas:

```
return View('welcome', compact('productos'));
```

Estas retornando el contenido de `welcome.blade.php` y no cambias la ruta.

En el caso que desees cambiar la ruta debes de re-direccionar la url con `redirect`:

```
return redirect('/')->with(compact('productos');
```